# Add json body to http4s Request

Tags: scala, http4s, http4s-circe

This tut shows how to create an http4s Request: https://http4s.org/v0.18/dsl/#testing-the-service

I would like to change this request to a POST method and add a literal json body using circe. I tried the following code:

```
val body = json"""{"hello":"world"}"""
val req = Request[IO](method = Method.POST, uri = Uri.uri("/"), body = body)
```

This gives me a type mismatch error:

```
[error]  found   : io.circe.Json
[error]  required: org.http4s.EntityBody[cats.effect.IO]
[error]     (which expands to)  fs2.Stream[cats.effect.IO,Byte]
[error]     val entity: EntityBody[IO] = body
```

I understand the error, but I cannot figure out how to convert `io.circe.Json` into an `EntityBody`. Most examples I have seen use an `EntityEncoder`, which does not provide the required type.

How can I convert `io.circe.Json` into an `EntityBody`?

Comment: I think that's exactly what's covered here: https://http4s.org/v0.18/json/

Comment: That page is showing how to use `EntityEncoder`s to create a `cats.effect.IO[org.http4s.Entity[cats.effect.IO]]` type.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Oleg's link mostly covers it, but here's how you'd do it for a custom request body:

```
import org.http4s.circe._

val body = json"""{"hello":"world"}"""
val req = Request[IO](method = Method.POST, uri = Uri.uri("/"))
  .withBody(body)
  .unsafeRunSync()
```

Explanation:

The parameter `body` on the request class is of type `EntityBody[IO]` which is an alias for `Stream[IO, Byte]`. You can't directly assign a String or Json object to it, you need to use the `withBody` method instead.

`withBody` takes an implicit `EntityEncoder` instance, so your comment about not wanting to use an `EntityEncoder` doesn't make sense - you *have* to use one if you don't want to create a byte stream yourself. However, the http4s library has predefined ones for a number of types, and the one for type `Json` lives in `org.http4s.circe._`. Hence the import statement.

Lastly, you need to call `.unsafeRunSync()` here to pull out a `Request` object because `withBody` returns an `IO[Request[IO]]`. The better way to handle this would of course be via chaining the result with other `IO` operations.

Comment: I edited my question to make it clear that it was not that I did not _want_ to use an EntityEncoder, but that it was not providing the required type.

Answer (score 13):

As of http4s 20.0, [withEntity](https://http4s.org/v0.20/api/org/http4s/response#withEntity[T](b:T)(implicitw:org.http4s.EntityEncoder[F,T]):Message.this.Self) overwrites the existing body (which defaults to empty) with the new body. The `EntityEncoder` is still required, and can be found with an import of `org.http4s.circe._`:

```scala
import org.http4s.circe._

val body = json"""{"hello":"world"}"""

val req = Request[IO](
  method = Method.POST,
  uri = Uri.uri("/")
)
.withEntity(body)
```